# MS Teams Graph API: PreconditionFailed-ETag mismatch for thread store resource while creating group chat

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to use $batch API from MS Team Graph API.

This is the payload I'm sending:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "48374fe8-7d16-460c-9dff-e5091a134407",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "chats/<GROUP-ID>/members",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      },
      "body": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<USER-ID>",
        "visibleHistoryStartDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "roles": ["owner"]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bbb5f15a-7d1d-4587-850b-d745359fced5",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "chats/<GROUP-ID>/members",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      },
      "body": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<USER-ID>",
        "visibleHistoryStartDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "roles": ["owner"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

While doing so I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "id": "fce02ff7-7919-40f9-8a87-2073a87f0af0",
  "status": 412,
  "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": "PreconditionFailed",
      "message": "PreconditionFailed",
      "innerError": {
        "message": "PreconditionFailed-ETag mismatch for thread store resource.",
        "code": "1",
        "innerError": {},
        "date": "2023-02-22T04:54:26",
        "request-id": "da580345-eafc-4b2e-986b-70ca496679ae",
        "client-request-id": "70042dab-3d24-4644-99e2-13d4ef19042a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Edit: Adding the curl request for the API.

Documentation Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
--header 'Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate' \
--data-raw '{"requests":[{"id":"48374fe8-7d16-460c-9dff-e5091a134407","method":"POST","url":"chats/<GROUP-ID>/members","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Cache-Control":"no-cache"},"body":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember","user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<USER-ID>","visibleHistoryStartDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","roles":["owner"]}}]}'
```

Comment: Could you please share the POST query which you are using along with repro steps and doc followed?

Comment: I've added it the curl request in the question

Comment: It seems like the POST request you are using is not valid one. Added the POST query which we used to create group chat using batch operation in 'Answer' section.

Answer (score -1):

We tried to create group chat using the batch operation and group chat got created successfully. Please check if you are using correct POST query

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "48374fe8-7d16-460c-9dff-e5091a134407",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/chats",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      },
      "body": {
         "members": [
        {"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4exxx4d0-xx1b-4154-xx5f-axxxd77aefa8",
        "roles": ["owner"]
         }]
    }},
{
      "id": "bbb5f15a-7d1d-4587-850b-d745359fced5",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/chats",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      },
      "body": {
         "members": [
        {"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4exxx4d0-xx1b-4154-xx5f-axxxd77aefa8",
        "roles": ["owner"]
         }]
    }}
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "48374fe8-7d16-460c-9dff-e5091a134407",
            "status": 201,
            "headers": {
                "Location": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
                "OData-Version": "4.0",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"
            },
            "body": {
                "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#chats/$entity",
                "id": "19:e6e4540ed22a49a28bde8203666ab39b@thread.v2",
                "topic": null,
                "createdDateTime": "2023-02-27T13:56:49.349Z",
                "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2023-02-27T13:56:49.349Z",
                "chatType": "group",
                "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/19%3Ae6e4540ed22a49a28bde8203666ab39b%40thread.v2/0?tenantId=xxx708ef-700d-4d60-9de0-xxxf7b7693df",
                "tenantId": "xxx708ef-700d-4d60-9de0-xxxf7b7693df",
                "viewpoint": null,
                "onlineMeetingInfo": null
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "bbb5f15a-7d1d-4587-850b-d745359fced5",
            "status": 201,
            "headers": {
                "Location": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
                "OData-Version": "4.0",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"
            },
            "body": {
                "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#chats/$entity",
                "id": "19:8edc24dbb7f34fc28813e45c00ae6bd6@thread.v2",
                "topic": null,
                "createdDateTime": "2023-02-27T13:56:49.713Z",
                "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2023-02-27T13:56:49.713Z",
                "chatType": "group",
                "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/19%3A8edc24dbb7f34fc28813e45c00ae6bd6%40thread.v2/0?tenantId=xxx708ef-700d-4d60-9de0-xxxf7b7693df",
                "tenantId": "xxx708ef-700d-4d60-9de0-xxxf7b7693df",
                "viewpoint": null,
                "onlineMeetingInfo": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After creating the group chat, tried adding members to those chat using batch operation as below and it got added successfully.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/chats/19:e6e4540ed22a49a28bde8203666ab39b@thread.v2/members",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      },
      "body": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
    "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/50ff3913-2766-4e6f-9edb-90d52bf26a1f",
    "visibleHistoryStartDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "roles": ["owner"]
}},
{
      "id": "2",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/chats/19:8edc24dbb7f34fc28813e45c00ae6bd6@thread.v2/members",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      },
      "body": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
    "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/50ff3913-2766-4e6f-9edb-90d52bf26a1f",
    "visibleHistoryStartDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "roles": ["owner"]
}
 }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "status": 201,
            "headers": {
                "Location": "/chats/19:e6e4540ed22a49a28bde8203666ab39b@thread.v2/members/MCMjMCMjMzZhNzA4ZWYtNzAwZC00ZDYwLTlkZTAtMGE1ZjdiNzY5M2RmIyMxOTplNmU0NTQwZWQyMmE0OWEyOGJkZTgyMDM2NjZhYjM5YkB0aHJlYWQudjIjIzUwZmYzOTEzLTI3NjYtNGU2Zi05ZWRiLTkwZDUyYmYyNmExZg=="
            },
            "body": null
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "status": 201,
            "headers": {
                "Location": "/chats/19:8edc24dbb7f34fc28813e45c00ae6bd6@thread.v2/members/MCMjMCMjMzZhNzA4ZWYtNzAwZC00ZDYwLTlkZTAtMGE1ZjdiNzY5M2RmIyMxOTo4ZWRjMjRkYmI3ZjM0ZmMyODgxM2U0NWMwMGFlNmJkNkB0aHJlYWQudjIjIzUwZmYzOTEzLTI3NjYtNGU2Zi05ZWRiLTkwZDUyYmYyNmExZg=="
            },
            "body": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: We have already created the group chat using the /chats API. $batch is the subsequent API call that we are doing after the group chat has been created to add the members to it.

Comment: Tried to add members to the created group chat using batch operation and it succeeded. Updated details in 'Answer' section for visibility.

Comment: Ok, but for me the same API is call failing.